# Re-creating a websites javascript function to be used as a stand alone alternative in tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I'm looking for a way to do something that may or may not be possible.

On the site http://hitbox.tv/ there is a javascript function I believe that turns text into images.

For example, using:

```
emotify.emoticons("",{
    "emote": ["http://example.com/emote.png", "channel"],    
});
```

in a tampermonkey script or entering it directly into the chrome console would allow all occurrences of "emote" in the chat to be turned into that image.

If I type "emotify" into the chrome console, I'm given:

```
function (e,f){return f=f||function(h,j,g){return j=(j+", "+g).replace(/"/g,"&quot;").replace(/</g,"&lt;"),'<img src="'+h+'" title="'+j+'" alt="" class="smiley"/>'},e.replace(b,function(j,g,m){var k=0,h=m,l=c[m];if(!l){for(;k<d.length&&!d[k].regexp.test(m);)k++;h=d[k].name,l=c[h]}return l?g+f(l[0],l[1],h,m):j})}
```

and if I type in "emotify.emoticons" I am given:

```
function (){var k,m,h,o,l=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),n="string"==typeof l[0]?l.shift():"",f="boolean"==typeof l[0]?l.shift():!1,g=l[0],j=[];if(g){f&&(c={},d=[]);for(k in g)c[k]=g[k],c[k][0]=n+c[k][0];for(k in c){if(c[k].length>2){for(m=c[k].slice(2).concat(k),h=m.length;h--;)m[h]=m[h].replace(/(\W)/g,"\\$1");o=m.join("|"),d.push({name:k,regexp:new RegExp("^"+o+"$")})}else o=k.replace(/(\W)/g,"\\$1");j.push(o)}b=new RegExp("(^|\\s)("+j.join("|")+")(?=(?:$|\\s))","g")}return c}
```

So what I'm wondering is, is there a way to use this code in a tampermonkey script somehow so that in the future, if the code is removed from the website, I could still use the emotify.emoticons function to create standalone emotes?

I really hope this makes sense. If you need any more information, fell free to ask. Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but my inclination is that no, you can't - because the full behavior for this code is probably actually executed server-side, not in the web browser.

1. The images would have to get passed to the server to get circulated to the other people in the chatbox anyway
2. The function you list just returns a function, which does some (somewhat cryptic!) string operations, and little else, indicating the heavy lifting is done elsewhere.

The reason why you can run it using tampermonkey currently is because the function is defined on hitbox.tv. Defining it in tampermonkey probably won't help, because if hitbox removed it, they would also remove everything that uses it, rendering it useless.

You can do more investigation if you feel like it; http://www.hitbox.tv/dist/hitbox-ui.min.js is the link to their (minified) javascript file that runs the website. Running it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ yields a ~55,000 line long file, however, so unless you know what other variable words to search for, it's going to be impractical to comb through by hand.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I had a look through the hitbox-ui.min.js a little before but all I could find in reference to the "emotes" was basically the code that I posted. Thanks for the help though, saved me a lot of time and trouble!